# Javascript: how to write a tracking pixel with a query string

Tags: javascript, ascii, query-string, pixel, encode

I need to put a tracking pixel into my html page. I'm using this snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var dataString="a=10&b=19";
    var track = new Image();
    track.src="http://pixel.tag.com/event/im.gif?" + dataString;
</script>
```

Why do I not need to encode the string contained in dataString? It could contain non ASCII character. Is there any reason?

Thanks,
Alessio

Comment: Who says you don't need to encode it?

Comment: I've never seen encoding in an img, and I had this doubt. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case the encoded string will be the same as the given one. this is why you don't have any issues with it.

```
'a=10&b=19' === encodeURI('a=10&b=19')
```

to keep the application flexible for future changes better encode your queryString.

Comment: Thanks @Votto. Sorry I did not take a good example for the queryString.

Comment: @AlessioG hope this answers your question and solves your problem.